# Matching free() and malloc() calls with regular expressions

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm creating a powershell script that parses a file containing C code and detects if it contains calls to **free()**, **malloc()** or **realloc()** functions.

### file_one.c

```
int MethodOne()  
{
    return 1;
}   
int MethodTwo()    
{   
    free();
    return 1;
}
```

---

### file_two.c

```
int MethodOne()  
{
    //free();
    return 1;
}
int MethodTwo()    
{       
    free();
    return 1;
}
```

---

### check.ps1

```
$regex = "(^[^/]*free\()|(^[^/]*malloc\()|(^[^/]*realloc\()"
$file_one= "Z:\PATH\file_one.txt"
$file_two= "Z:\PATH\file_two.txt"

$contentOne = Get-Content $file_one -Raw 
$contentOne -match $regex

$contentTwo = Get-Content $file_two-Raw 
$contentTwo -match $regex
```

---

processing the whole file in a time seems to work well with ***contentOne***, 
in fact I get ***True*** (because of the free() in MethodTwo).
Processing ***contentTwo*** is not so lucky and returns False instead of True
(because of the free() in MethodTwo).

Can someone help me to write a better regex that works in both cases?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20961630

Comment: That other regex doesn't handle comments. However, I did find if I removed the `-Raw` and used `($contentTwo -match $regex).Count -ne 0`, it returns `True`. Another alternative is `$contentTwo | select-string -Pattern $regex -Quiet`

Comment: @Eris doing this turns out the problem that every call to this functions made whithin a multiline comment  /*  */will be considered as a match

Comment: Truthfully, regex is a poor choice for this, since C has a formal grammar. You're better off running the files through the C preprocessor to get the tokens

Comment: There is a regex that excludes comments and string literals then finds your target words. Want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this is it

Raw:

```
^(?>(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\]|\\(?:\r?\n)?)*?(?:\r?\n))|(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|(?!\b(?:free|malloc|realloc)\()[\S\s](?:(?!\b(?:free|malloc|realloc)\()[^/"'\\])*))*(?:(\bfree\()|(\bmalloc\()|(\brealloc\())
```

Stringed:

```
"^(?>(?:/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\\\]|\\\\(?:\\r?\\n)?)*?(?:\\r?\\n))|(?:\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\\S\\s][^\"\\\\]*)*\"|'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\\S\\s][^'\\\\]*)*'|(?!\\b(?:free|malloc|realloc)\\()[\\S\\s](?:(?!\\b(?:free|malloc|realloc)\\()[^/\"'\\\\])*))*(?:(\\bfree\\()|(\\bmalloc\\()|(\\brealloc\\())"
```

Verbatim:

```
@"^(?>(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\]|\\(?:\r?\n)?)*?(?:\r?\n))|(?:""[^""\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^""\\]*)*""|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|(?!\b(?:free|malloc|realloc)\()[\S\s](?:(?!\b(?:free|malloc|realloc)\()[^/""'\\])*))*(?:(\bfree\()|(\bmalloc\()|(\brealloc\())"
```

Explained

```
 ^ 
 (?>
      (?:                              # Comments 
           /\*                              # Start /* .. */ comment
           [^*]* \*+
           (?: [^/*] [^*]* \*+ )*
           /                                # End /* .. */ comment
        |  
           //                               # Start // comment
           (?:                              # Possible line-continuation
                [^\\] 
             |  \\ 
                (?: \r? \n )?
           )*?
           (?: \r? \n )                     # End // comment
      )
   |                                 # OR,

      (?:                              # Non - comments 
           "
           [^"\\]*                          # Double quoted text
           (?: \\ [\S\s] [^"\\]* )*
           "
        |  '
           [^'\\]*                          # Single quoted text
           (?: \\ [\S\s] [^'\\]* )*
           ' 
        |                                 # OR,

           (?!                              # ASSERT: Here, cannot be free / malloc / realloc {}
                \b 
                (?: free | malloc | realloc )
                \(
           )
           [\S\s]                           # Any char which could start a comment, string, etc..
                                            # (Technically, we're going past a C++ source code error)

           (?:                              # -------------------------
                (?!                              # ASSERT: Here, cannot be free / malloc / realloc {}
                     \b 
                     (?: free | malloc | realloc )
                     \(
                )

                [^/"'\\]                         # Char which doesn't start a comment, string, escape,
                                                 # or line continuation (escape + newline)
           )*                               # -------------------------
      )                                # Done Non - comments 
 )*

 (?:
      ( \b free\( )                    # (1), Free()
   |  
      ( \b malloc\( )                  # (2), Malloc()
   |  
      ( \b realloc\( )                 # (3), Realloc()
 )
```

Some notes:

This only finds the first one from the beginning of string using `^` anchor.
To find them all, just remove the `^` from the regex.

This works because it matches everything up to what you're looking for.
In this case, what it found is in capture group 1, 2, or 3.

*Good Luck !!*

---

What the regex contains:

```
----------------------------------
 * Format Metrics
----------------------------------
Atomic Groups       =   1

Cluster Groups      =   10

Capture Groups      =   3

Assertions          =   2
       ( ? !        =   2

Free Comments       =   25
Character Classes   =   12
```

---

***edit***
Per request, explanation of the part of the regex that handles
`/**/` comments. This -> `/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/`

This is a modified unrolled-loop regex that assumes an opening delimiter
of `/*` and a closing one of `*/`.
Notice that the open/close share a common character `/` in it's delimiter
sequence.
To be able to do this without lookaround assertions, a method is used
to shift the trailing delimiter's asterisk inside the loop.
Using this factoring, all that's needed is to check for a closing `/`
to complete the delimited sequence.

```
 /\*              # Opening delimiter /*

 [^*]*            # Optionally, consume all non-asterisks

 \*+              # This must be 1 or more asterisks anchor's or FAIL.
                  # This is matched here to align the optional loop below
                  # because it is looking for the closing /.

 (?:              # The optional loop part
      [^/*]            # Specifically a single non / character (nor asterisk).
                       # Since a / will be the next closing delimiter, it must be excluded.

      [^*]*            # Optional non-asterisks.
                       # This will accept a / because it is supposed to consume ALL
                       # opening delimiter's as it goes
                       # and will consider the very next */ as a close.

      \*+              # This must be 1 or more asterisks anchor's or FAIL.
 )*               # Repeat 0 to many times.

 /                # Closing delimiter /
```

Comment: There are some double quotes in the raw regex. If your shell doesn't use escapes for strings, you'll have to escape it with double/triple escapes ?

Comment: Also, this regex uses newline `\n` only detection. If you open the file translated, you may have to change them to `(?:\r\n)` verbatim, or `(?:\r?\n)` covers both.

Comment: I don't understand very well the part of comments (both // and /* */). Could you kindly explain these parts with more details?

Comment: @GiorgioGambino - First of all, did the regex work ? The `/**/` form uses this `/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/` it's a specially designed modified unrolled-loop that is fast and distinctly matches from here `/*` to here `*/` that will consume any new `/*` in the middle. The `//` form uses this `//(?:[^\\]|\\(?:\r?\n)?)*?(?:\r?\n)` which passively (optionally) consumes line continuation `escape + newline` until it finds an un-escaped newline that terminates the line comment `//`

Comment: Yes it works well! What is not clear to me is the central part `[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)` the other part (the one for // comments ) is now clear.

Comment: @GiorgioGambino - The `/**/` parsing part is just an unrolled loop as I said. What makes it strange is that the open/close delimiter share a forward slash which would require an assertion. This is how to do it without assertion's. I've edit my post with a detailed description. If this were a test of speed, this would be the fastest possible way for this to be done.