# Making a regex pattern created for C# work in PHP

Tags: c#, php, regex

I found the following [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18908330/3955740), in which it is described how to use a regex pattern to extract (nested) functions and arguments from a string.

The user also provides an example for which the pattern should work, and after he extracts the arguments from the most-outer function (which works fine in php too), he matches the following text

```
a,b,func1(a,b+c),func2(a*b,func3(a+b,c)),func4(e)+func5(f),func6(func7(g,h)+func8(i,(a)=>a+2)),g+2
```

with the following pattern

```
(?:[^,()]+((?:\((?>[^()]+|\((?<open>)|\)(?<-open>))*(?(open)(?!))\)))*)+
```

The following (simpler) pattern is also supposed to work

```
(?:[^,()]+((?:\((?>[^()]+|\((?<open>)|\)(?<-open>))*\)))*)+
```

Note that the user was using C# for his example, and I want to get it to work in PHP, however I can't manage to do it.

So when I try to match the example String using `preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)`, it doesn't return any matches.

If I enter the pattern and the example on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iJ7jV0/1), it's giving me errors and I can't fix them (I guess it has something to do with the `<open>` part of the pattern).

I'm not the best in regex, so can someone please help me out and tell me what I need to change in the pattern for it to work with php?

Comment: Your `regex101` link doesn't contain any regex or examples

Comment: I've had this problem in reverse. Unfortunately the Microsoft regex parser is slightly different from the Linux one

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight sorry, fixed it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, looking at the original answer you linked to and the errors on Regex101, PHP's `preg_match()` function isn't as powerful as C#'s `Regex.Matches()` function, and what you're attempting simply isn't possible using only regex in PHP.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight Thanks for the answer. Well that's a bummer

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight this is simply false. They are different. PHP uses PCRE, which is arguably **more** powerful than what .NET offers. You just need to use a different technique. I'll write an answer to demonstrate that.

Comment: @Ewan FYI, I've made a PCRE wrapper for .NET: [PCRE.NET](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net), if you still want to reuse your PCRE regex as-is you can try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP uses the [PCRE](http://pcre.org/) regex engine to implement its `preg_*` functions. PCRE can match nested patterns using [recursion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html), whereas .NET uses a different approach: [balancing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406/3764814). And there are other major [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26504537/3764814) between the two flavors.

So what you want to achieve is definitely possible, but requires to rewrite the regex entirely, since both approaches are *totally* different.

Here's such a translation for PCRE (with `gx`):

```
(?:
  [^,()]++         # match a function name
  (?<args>         # open the "args" group
    \(             # opening parenthesis
    (?:
      [^()]++      # match anything but parentheses
      | \g<args>   # or recurse into "args", make sure the parentheses are balanced
    )*+
    \)             # closing parenthesis
  )*+
)+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tY9qB9/2)

Or, in shorter form:

```
(?:[^,()]++(?<args>\((?:[^()]++|\g<args>)*+\))*+)+
```